# VBA: Find last element in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 columns of data with 3 subsets of information (separated by blank rows). I would like to identify a lower bound and upper bound according to the last value in the third set of items. The third set of items changes length. In this example length = 3 Visualized:

[Spreadsheet View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtSkD.png)

Currently for my code I have the following to return the value of the upper bound and lower bound for the list of doubles

```
curvesSheet = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
tlb(n) = curvesSheet(10, 1)
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
tub(n) = curvesSheet(lrow, 1)
```

Right now, lRow returns 1 when I am trying to get it to return 12. I thought xlUp went from the bottom of the sheet and

```
?Rows.Count
 1048576
```

as expected... any and all suggestions are thoroughly appreciated.

Edit: Please note that the sheet pictured is converted to a Variant array earlier in the code so I must use matrix indices to access values and not cell names.

Comment: Are you sure you are working on the correct sheet?  You need to assign the parent sheet to all your range variables.  `lRow = curvesSheet.Cells(curvesSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row`

Comment: Fixed. Thank you! If you submit an answer I'll up vote it.